# How cv2.imshow() function works in BGR model?

Tags: python, image, opencv

In RGB color model, `cv2.imshow()` works by bgr order,when use `cv2.imshow()` to load a image,and show it in `matplotlib.plot.show()` function,it goes wrong cause plot.show() use rgb order,it can be solved by reverse the channels of b,g,r in image,but when I make RGB color model transformation into other color model,like HSV,YUV,YCbCr,when use `plot.show()` it still be different to `cv2.show()`.So when RGB->HSV,YUV,YCbCr color model,does `cv2.show()` still works like v,s,h maps to b,g,r?And `plt.show()` use the order h,s,v maps to r,g,b?No matter what color model use `cv2.show()` and `plot.show()`,it just use b,g,r and r,g,b orders maps to changed channels?Like v,s,h and h,s,v in HSV,v,u,y and y,u,v in YUV?

```py
img_HSV = cv2.cvtColor(img_BGR, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
plt.show(img_HSV )
cv2.show(img_HSV )
plt.show(img_HSV [:,:,::-1])
```

the result in line 1 code is different with line2,but line 3 is same as line2.
So `plt.show` works by h,s,v maps to r,g,b and cv2.show works by v,s,h maps to b,g,r?

Answer (score 1):

`plt.show(img_HSV )` assumes the input is RGB
`cv2.show(img_HSV )` assumes the input is BGR

So if you give input in a different format they take the channel as they assume anyway. For example, `cv2.imshow(img_HSV )` method will take the Hue value as Blue so there will be a different image representation.

So just convert them back to RGB or BGR for `imshow()` functions after your processes done with the other color spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean `cv2.imshow` (and `plt.imshow`) as in your title, right? Most of the time (and in all your examples) you pass an image with three channels to the functions `plt.imshow` and `cv2.imshow`.

Those are numpy arrays and the data type (uint8, float32, ect) is the only information you implicitly pass along. So those functions simply don't know which color encoding you are currently using. They simply interpret it as RGB (matplotlib) respectively BGR (OpenCV). So the second channel will always be interpreted as green and the other ones as red and blue respectively. That's all they do.

PS: If you pass a single-channel array you'll get a gray image.

PPS: Consider the range of the values in your numpy array. For example if you are passing float the values should be in the interval [0-1], whereas with uint8 it's [0-255] for matplotlib.